# Jmeter correlating SAML request

Tags: jmeter, saml

I have to capture the SAML response in Jmeter. After capturing using Regular Expression Extractor, Jmeter is automatically changing the value of "=" to "%3D". "+" symbol remains same.
URL Encode option is also disabled.
I have tried using replace function in Beanshell preprocessor. I am not able to do it successfully.
Kindly help me to fix the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. As per [Wikipedia article on SAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language)

   > SAML is an **XML-based** markup language for security assertions (statements that service providers use to make access-control decisions).

   Given it's [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) it makes more sense to go for [XPath2 Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-xpath2-extractor-how-to-achieve-better-correlations/) for the correlation which could resolve your issue
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting so if the problem remains even after using XPath2 Extractor you could try the following code snippet:

   ```
   vars.put('foo', java.net.URLDecoder.decode(vars.get('foo')))
   ```

   Replace `foo` with the actual JMeter Variable name from the XPath2 Extractor

   Demo:

   [image]